# Calling check internet connectivity class when clicking a button from another activity

Tags: android, class, broadcastreceiver

What i have is an android application , i have an activity which check if internet connectivity exist or not and here it is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CheckNetworkStatus";
     private NetworkChangeReceiver receiver;
     private boolean isConnected = false;
     private TextView networkStatus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
          receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
          registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

          networkStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.networkStatus);
         }


         @Override
         protected void onDestroy() {
          Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDestory");
          super.onDestroy();

          unregisterReceiver(receiver);

         }


         public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

          @Override
          public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

           Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
           isNetworkAvailable(context);

          }


          private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
           ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
           if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
             for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
              if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
               if(!isConnected){
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                networkStatus.setText("Now you are connected to Internet!");
                isConnected = true;
                //do your processing here ---
                //if you need to post any data to the server or get status
                //update from the server
               }
               return true;
              }
             }
            }
           }
           Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
           networkStatus.setText("You are not connected to Internet!");
           isConnected = false;
           return false;
          }
         }


        }
```

And i have another Activity which has a button , and i want when i click the button to check if internet connectivity exist it will make a toast in this activity without opening the internet activity , here is my button :

```
  Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

How can i make the other Activity work start on a click without make it visible on the application? 
Am new At android .. please help :(

Comment: You can keep the receiver as main class instead of inner class of your activity, and use it anywhere in project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create separate class for checking internet connection and you can access that class from any other class by calling it through its object here is the example.

save below code with **ConnectionDetector.java**

```
package com.yourpackagename;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

in activity where you want to use to check connectivity use below code

first create object of above **ConnectionDetector** class

```
ConnectionDetector cd;
```

then intialise it by

```
cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);
```

then use below code anywhere you want in that activity like on button click event.

```
if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
    //no internet present
} else {
    //internet present
}
```